# PostGIS: Overlay without dissolving boundaries (Union) & keeping attributes

Tags: postgis, union

**Problem**

I need a geometric union of a set of polygon layers (like Union in ArcGIS or QGIS) and because  the datasets large and calculation time becomes very long in QGIS (I don't have an ArcGIS license) I am looking for a PostGIS solution.

**What I have tried**

The solution I found here would exactly fulfill my needs, but fail to implement the examples correctly:
https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiExamplesOverlayTables

Assuming two tables as input layers (test.input01 and test.input02 with the fields id01 and id02) I adapted the examples as shown below.

Using the first example provided by Kevin Neufeld the result is a table with no rows, when I try to load it to QGIS, there is the message “Unavailable layer!”.

Using the second example by Chris Hodgson leads to the Error message “Syntax error at »varchar«”, there seems to be a problem with schemas(?).

What am I doing wrong?

*Adapted example 1*

```
--Extract the linework from the polygons (you may wish to add any interior rings to this query). 

CREATE TEMP TABLE all_lines AS
SELECT St_ExteriorRing(input01.geom) AS the_geom
FROM test.input01
UNION ALL
SELECT St_ExteriorRing(input02.geom) AS the_geom
FROM test.input02;

-- Node the linework: 

CREATE TEMP TABLE noded_lines AS
SELECT St_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom
FROM all_lines;

-- Re-polygonize all linework: 

CREATE TEMP TABLE new_polys (id serial PRIMARY KEY, the_geom geometry);
INSERT INTO new_polys (the_geom)
SELECT geom AS the_geom
FROM St_Dump((
 SELECT St_Polygonize(the_geom) AS the_geom
 FROM noded_lines
));

-- Transfer attributes from original polygons to newly formed polygons
-- Create point-in-polygon features. 

CREATE TEMP TABLE new_polys_pip AS
SELECT id, ST_PointOnSurface(the_geom) AS the_geom
FROM new_polys;

-- Overlay points with original polygons, transferring the attributes. 

CREATE TEMP TABLE pip_with_attributes AS
SELECT a.id, f.id01, c.id02
FROM new_polys_pip a
LEFT JOIN test.input01 f ON St_Within(a.the_geom, f.geom)
LEFT JOIN test.input02 c ON St_Within(a.the_geom, c.geom);

-- Join the points to the newly formed polygons, transferring the attributes: 

CREATE TABLE test.union_try AS
SELECT *
FROM new_polys a LEFT JOIN pip_with_attributes b USING (id);
```

*Adapted example 2*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_overlay(test.input01 varchar, id01 varchar, test.input02 varchar, id02 varchar, test.result_table varchar) returns void AS 
$$ 
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || result_table || ' AS '
|| 'WITH all_lines AS ( '
    || 'SELECT St_ExteriorRing(st_geometryn(the_geom,1)) AS the_geom '
    || 'FROM ' || test.input01
    || ' UNION ALL '
    || 'SELECT St_ExteriorRing(st_geometryn(the_geom,1)) AS the_geom '
    || 'FROM ' || test.input02
|| '), noded_lines AS ( '
    || 'SELECT St_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom '
    || 'FROM all_lines '
|| '), new_polys AS (  '
    || 'SELECT geom AS the_geom, ST_PointOnSurface(geom) AS pip '
    || 'FROM St_Dump(( '
        || 'SELECT St_Polygonize(the_geom) AS the_geom '
        || 'FROM noded_lines)) '
|| ') '
|| 'SELECT a.' || id01 || ' as ' || test.input01 || '_' || id01 
|| ', b.' || id02 || ' as ' || test.input02 || '_' || id02 
|| ', p.the_geom as the_geom '
|| 'FROM new_polys p '
|| 'LEFT JOIN ' || test.input01 || ' a ON St_Within(p.pip, a.the_geom) '
|| 'LEFT JOIN ' || test.input02 || ' b ON St_Within(p.pip, b.the_geom)';
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: For the 1st solution, try looking at the temp table content after each step. For the 2nd solution, you can use the provided function as-is. Just call the function using your parameters, like `select my_overlay('test.input01', 'id01', 'test.input02', 'id02', 'test.result_table'); select * from test.result_table;`)

Comment: I managed to apply the 1st solution. The reason for the NULL result was that St_ExteriorRing does not support multipolgons. After creating polygons with ST_Dump it works.